# Regex match character only when NOT preceeded by specific word

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

The goal is to have regex match all newline character which are not preceded by a 2-decimal number. Here's some example text:

```
This line ends with text
this line ends with a number: 55
this line ends with a 2-decimal number: 5.00
here's 22.22, not at the end of the line
```

Regex should match the end of lines 1, 2, and 4 (assuming a newline after the 4th line).  I thought negative lookahead was the answer so I tried

```
(?!\d*\.\d\d)\n
```

without success as seen in this regex101 snippet: https://regex101.com/r/qbrKlt/4

> <s>Edit: I later discovered the reason this didn't work is because Python's Regex doesn't support variable length negative lookahead - it only supports fixed-length negative lookahead.</s>

Unfortunately fixed-length look-ahead still didnt work:

```
(?!\.\d\d)\n
```

Instead I did a workaround by running regex twice & subtracting the result:

1. find all indices of newline characters: `\n`
2. find all indices of newline characters preceded by 2-decimal numbers: `\d*\.\d\d\n`
3. remove indices found in step 2 from those found in step 1 for the answer

But I'm sure there's a way to do this in 1 go and I'd be grateful to anyone out there that can help in discovering the solution :)

Comment: Why should it match the second line?

Comment: *Python's Regex doesn't support variable length negative lookahead* - wrong, `re` supports variable-width lookaheads. It does not support unknown width **lookbehind** patterns.

Comment: Incorrect dupe: This question is not just about use of lookbehind it is about handing a very specific case of unknown width lookbehind pattern in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookbehind instead of a negative lookahead:

```
(?<!\.\d\d)\n
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qbrKlt/5)

This will match `\n` if that is not immediately preceded by dot and 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Why get esoteric with regexes, when you can just capture the final word using string.split()[-1] and test that for the form you need?  Python isn't Perl (fortunately).